# How can I login via HTTPS and still navigate on HTTP as logged?

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

In Symfony, If i login with `HTTPS` mode, I redirected to `HTTPS` routes always. If i change it to `HTTP` from address bar, It asks me my password again.

I want to login via `HTTPS` but stay at `HTTP` mode on other pages (unless i go for sensitive datas) How can i achieve this?

Should i make another cookie for **HTTP** inside of a controller after user login via **HTTPS**? And check if cookie is valid on `http`?

I want to do this:

1. David sign in to website with username and password at
   `https://a.login`
2. David redirected to `https://a.admin/` (as it is https because of admin page)
3. David now press a button and admin panel redirects unimportant page. Called **http**://a.somepage (**not** https)
4. But my website (symfony) should know that this is David. But instead asks password and username again. Because it came from HTTPS to HTTTP

I am using Symfony's standard `SecurityBundle`. What is the correct way of auth with two mode (http/s) at the same time?

**Real World Example:**

**StackOverflow** do the same thing. I hit `log in` and redirects to `https` and **after successful login** i get back here with `HTTP` only. Is there something that i missed?

Comment: A good question, but I ask myself: why would you want to return the user to oldskool HTTP? If you have a valid SSL certificate, there is no reason nowadays to still use HTTP.

Comment: There is no specific reason. Of course, HTTPS should be always **on**. But how can I do this? I know it can be. I know thousands of websites like this. For example; I am planning to use custom subdomains. I cannot buy SSL for each user's subdomains right?But this is another subject :)

Comment: after login in https if you return on http all data will be passed in clear on each request and readable by any attacker. PS: the websites that using this method are unsafe! (but depend which data are you using on)

Comment: @gp_sflover, Stackoverflow does the same thing. I press **log in** it redirects to https and after successful login i get back here with HTTP only. Is there something different that i missed?

Comment: If on your website users can do important operations during the login time return on http after login is a bad approach, but if not (like stackoverflow) you can do it but at your own risk. You can find hundreds of threads about login security googling a bit.

Comment: @Blaatpraat: _“there is no reason nowadays to still use HTTP”_ – well, there might still be one: Caching. HTTPS resources are usually not cached by browsers.

Comment: @gp_sflover: I can -for example- let user login my site and then return with unique key. Also Symfony Session and database processing. After that if user has this token/unique id in its browser no matter of https or http, I can check from DB/Sessions. I googled and found tons of thing, yes. But which path should i go with it?

Comment: @CBroe, Yes thats one count too. I can do basic thing like my above message but i want to know correct way on Symfony2.

Comment: It's a very large argument and the final choice does not depends by Symfony (symfony is only a tool) but depends by many factors like: which operations users can do on your website and which relevant data type are involved during this operations? Basing on this and on many other factors you can evaluate how to proceed and which level of security to apply.

Comment: @gp_sflover you might be right about saying `final choice does not depends by Symfony`. Thanks.

Comment: It was referring to the phrase in your previous comment `i want to know correct way on Symfony2` but I probably misunderstood due to my low english level. To answer your question it's better to post also all code related (firewall.yml, etc...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Nelmio

I found this bundle on GitHub. It does what i want and more. I suggest and pick this as an answer.

> **Flexible HTTPS/SSL Handling:** If you don't want to force all users to
>   use HTTPS, you should at least use secure session cookies and force
>   SSL for logged-in users. But then logged-in users appear logged-out
>   when they access a non-HTTPS resource. This is not really a good
>   solution. This will make the application detect logged-in users and
>   redirect them to a secure URL, without making the session cookie
>   insecure.

**Refer**: https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSecurityBundle#flexible-httpsssl-handling